# LaTex errors: unit of measure (pt inserted)

Tags: latex

I met this problem in LaTex. Although I know what is the error message meaning, I have no idea about how to solve this error in my task.

```
\newcommand*{\MinNumber}{0}%
\newcommand*{\MaxNumber}{1.2}%
\pgfmathsetmacro{\MidNumber}{(0.8}%
\def\test#1{\ifdim#1pt>\MidNumber\textcolor{gray!70}{#1}\else{#1}\fi}
\newcommand{\ApplyGradient}[2]{\centering %
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\PercentColor}{100.0*(#1-\MinNumber)/(\MaxNumber-\MinNumber)}%
  \edef\x{\noexpand\cellcolor{black!\PercentColor}}\x\test{#1}
}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\collectcell\ApplyGradient}p{1.1cm}<{\endcollectcell}}
\newcolumntype{S}{>{\collectcell\ApplyGradient}p{0.6cm}<{\endcollectcell}}
%
\begin{table}[!ht]
\centering
\small
% \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.9}
% \begin{adjustbox}{width=0.8\textwidth}
\begin{tabular}{>{\centering}p{1.3cm}|>{\centering}p{0.9cm}|R R R R R }
\multicolumn{2}{c}{testing in$\rightarrow$}& \multicolumn{1}{c} {$\ang{40}$}  & \multicolumn{1}{c} {$\ang{20}$}  & \multicolumn{1}{c} {$\ang{0}$}  & \multicolumn{1}{c} {$-\ang{20}$}  & \multicolumn{1}{c} {$-\ang{40}$} \\ \midrule
            & $\ang{40}$    & 0.52  & 0.44  & 0.27  & 0.10  & -0.01 \\
            & $\ang{20}$    & 0.47  & 0.49  & 0.35  & 0.19  & 0.07 \\
spider9     & $\ang{0}$     & 0.25  & 0.47  & 0.63  & 0.46  & 0.24 \\
            & $-\ang{20}$   & 0.05  & 0.17  & 0.35  & 0.55  & 0.54 \\
            & $-\ang{40}$   & 0.0   & 0.05  & 0.21  & 0.47  &  0.77 \\ 
\midrule
            & $\ang{40}$   & 0.75  & 0.69  & 0.40  & 0.17  & 0.04 \\
            & $\ang{20}$   & 0.72  & 0.82  & 0.59  & 0.30  & 0.10 \\
gecko7      & $\ang{0}$    & 0.31  & 0.65  & 1.06  & 0.96  & 0.56 \\
            & $-\ang{20}$  & 0.16  & 0.45  & 0.86  & 1.18  & 0.98 \\
            & $-\ang{40}$  & 0.03  & 0.15  & 0.40  & 0.74  & 0.96 \\ 
\midrule
            & $\ang{40}$   & 1.09  & 0.75  & 0.39  & 0.14  & 0.02 \\
            & $\ang{20}$   & 0.54  & 0.55  & 0.33  & 0.15  & 0.04 \\
babyA       & $\ang{0}$    & 0.29  & 0.58  & 0.88  & 0.74  & 0.42 \\
            & $-\ang{20}$  & 0.18  & 0.47  & 0.85  & 1.09  & 0.71 \\
            & $-\ang{40}$  & 0.02  & 0.11  & 0.33  & 0.65  & 0.91 \\
\bottomrule            
\end{tabular}
%
\begin{tabular}{p{0.4cm} S}
& 0.0 \\
& 0.1 \\
& 0.2 \\
& 0.3 \\
& 0.4 \\
& 0.5 \\
& 0.6 \\
& 0.7 \\
& 0.8 \\
& 0.9 \\
& 1.0 \\
& 1.1 \\
& 1.2 \\
\end{tabular}
% \end{adjustbox}
\caption{Robustness of the top learned controllers for different directions in the real world. 
The data shows the fitness that the top controllers of three robots in 5 directions (the second column) perform in another directions (the first row). 
The fitness value in a cell is averaged over three controller and three repetitions for each controller. 
The dark and light color represent the high and low fitness value respectively.}
\label{tab:robustness}
\end{table}
```

The table shows as the picture:
[image]

But I got a lot errors like:

Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).

\protect 
l.1545             & $\ang{40}$    & 0.52  &
                                             0.44  & 0.27  & 0.10  & -0.01 \
Dimensions can be in units of em, ex, in, pt, pc,
cm, mm, dd, cc, nd, nc, bp, or sp; but yours is a new one!
I'll assume that you meant to say pt, for printer's points.
To recover gracefully from this error, it's best to
delete the erroneous units; e.g., type `2' to delete
two letters. (See Chapter 27 of The TeXbook.)

! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
 
                   \protect 
l.1545 ...       & $\ang{40}$    & 0.52  & 0.44  &
                                                   0.27  & 0.10  & -0.01 \
Dimensions can be in units of em, ex, in, pt, pc,
cm, mm, dd, cc, nd, nc, bp, or sp; but yours is a new one!
I'll assume that you meant to say pt, for printer's points.
To recover gracefully from this error, it's best to
delete the erroneous units; e.g., type `2' to delete
two letters. (See Chapter 27 of The TeXbook.)

Could you give me hands to solve this problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some considerations:

- While `\MinNumber` is defined to be `0`, you have a number that is smaller than that in the table (`-0.01`).
- If you're performing a test on `dim`ensions (`\ifdim <dimA><relation><dimB>`) you need to make sure both `<dimA>` and `<dimB>` are dimensions. In your case you have

  ```
  \ifdim#1pt>\MidNumber
  ```

  and `\MidNumber` is clearly not a dimension. It is just a number (`0.8`). That's the main cause of the problem.
- `\ApplyGradient` should only take a single argument, not two.
- It's awkward to use [`booktabs`](//ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) together with vertical rules in a `tabular`. There's no real need for them; I've kept them in the output, but you don't need them.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}% Just for this example
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs,collcell,xfp}

\newcommand*{\ang}[2]{#1^\circ}
\newcommand*{\MinNumber}{-0.01}%
\newcommand*{\MaxNumber}{1.2}%
\newcommand*{\MidNumber}{0.8}%

\newcommand{\test}[2]{\ifdim#1pt>\MidNumber pt\textcolor{gray!70}{#1}\else #1\fi}

\newcommand{\ApplyGradient}[2]{\centering %
  \edef\x{\noexpand\cellcolor{black!\fpeval{100*(#1-\MinNumber)/(\MaxNumber-\MinNumber)}}}\x\test{#1}
}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\collectcell\ApplyGradient}p{1.1cm}<{\endcollectcell}}
\newcolumntype{S}{>{\collectcell\ApplyGradient}p{0.6cm}<{\endcollectcell}}
%

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{
    >{\centering}p{1.3cm} |
    >{\centering}p{0.9cm} |
    *{5}{R}
  }
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{testing in$\rightarrow$} & 
      \multicolumn{1}{c}{$\ang{40}$} & 
      \multicolumn{1}{c}{$\ang{20}$} & 
      \multicolumn{1}{c}{$\ang{0}$}  & 
      \multicolumn{1}{c}{$-\ang{20}$} & 
      \multicolumn{1}{c}{$-\ang{40}$} \\
    \midrule
                & $\ang{40}$  & 0.52 & 0.44 & 0.27 & 0.10 & -0.01 \\
                & $\ang{20}$  & 0.47 & 0.49 & 0.35 & 0.19 &  0.07 \\
    spider9     & $\ang{0}$   & 0.25 & 0.47 & 0.63 & 0.46 &  0.24 \\
                & $-\ang{20}$ & 0.05 & 0.17 & 0.35 & 0.55 &  0.54 \\
                & $-\ang{40}$ & 0.0  & 0.05 & 0.21 & 0.47 &  0.77 \\
    \midrule
                & $\ang{40}$  & 0.75 & 0.69 & 0.40 & 0.17 &  0.04 \\
                & $\ang{20}$  & 0.72 & 0.82 & 0.59 & 0.30 &  0.10 \\
    gecko7      & $\ang{0}$   & 0.31 & 0.65 & 1.06 & 0.96 &  0.56 \\
                & $-\ang{20}$ & 0.16 & 0.45 & 0.86 & 1.18 &  0.98 \\
                & $-\ang{40}$ & 0.03 & 0.15 & 0.40 & 0.74 &  0.96 \\
    \midrule
                & $\ang{40}$  & 1.09 & 0.75 & 0.39 & 0.14 &  0.02 \\
                & $\ang{20}$  & 0.54 & 0.55 & 0.33 & 0.15 &  0.04 \\
    babyA       & $\ang{0}$   & 0.29 & 0.58 & 0.88 & 0.74 &  0.42 \\
                & $-\ang{20}$ & 0.18 & 0.47 & 0.85 & 1.09 &  0.71 \\
                & $-\ang{40}$ & 0.02 & 0.11 & 0.33 & 0.65 &  0.91 \\
    \bottomrule            
  \end{tabular}
  \hspace{4mm}
  \begin{tabular}{ S }
    0.0 \\ 0.1 \\ 0.2 \\ 0.3 \\ 0.4 \\ 0.5 \\
    0.6 \\ 0.7 \\ 0.8 \\ 0.9 \\ 1.0 \\ 1.1 \\
    1.2
  \end{tabular}

  \caption{Robustness of the top learned controllers for different directions in the real world. 
    The data shows the fitness that the top controllers of three robots in~5 directions (the second column) perform in another directions (the first row). 
    The fitness value in a cell is averaged over three controller and three repetitions for each controller. 
    The dark and light color represent the high and low fitness value respectively.}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: cool, Thanks a lot! How do you know so many details? Could you give me some ideas that I can fix some other latex problem like this by myself? I mean I want to learn to fix something like you rather than post it to ask help again next time.

Comment: one more issue, this is working without any errors in Overleaf. But when I submitted it to Arxiv. It has some problem with package xfp as: ```! LaTeX Error: File `xfp.sty' not found.```

Comment: @GongjinLan: Arxiv might not have [`xfp`](//ctan.org/pkg/xfp) installed. You can revert back to your use of [`tikz`](//ctan.org/pkg/tikz) (or `pgfmath`) for performing the calculations and try again. Practice helps to solve problems, but ultimately you need to look at the source code to understand how things are put together. Spending lots of time digging through problems makes you better at solving them.

Comment: nice, thanks a lot for your answer. I kind of solved this issues.